# SuiteScript method does not seem to be called

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I have created a script to email the created record to me when a Sales Order is created. The code below runs perfectly on a NetSuite Sandbox account, which I used for testing. On the production site however, I never receive the expected email. I have enabled suitescript and specified my email in the email preferences.

When I deliberately create a syntax error, this is picked up when a sales order is created. So it seems that the script is connected to the creation of sales orders, yet the method is not executed. I am not sure what I am missing..

My script:

```
function OnAfterSubmit(dataIn) {
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;


var newRecord = nlapiGetNewRecord();
var fromId = -5; //Authors' Internal ID
var sbj = 'test subject';
var msg = '';  

//Create Text File

var recordAsJSON = JSON.stringify(newRecord);
var newFileObj = nlapiCreateFile('SalesOrder.json', 'PLAINTEXT', recordAsJSON);

if (nlapiGetFieldValue('location') === '3' && nlapiGetFieldValue('status') === 'Pending Fulfillment' && nlapiGetFieldValue('trandate') === today) {
    nlapiSendEmail(fromId, 'email@test.com', sbj, msg, null, null, null, newFileObj);
}
```

}

As I mentioned, this script runs in the sandbox account. So i don't think the script is incorrect.

[Script Setup screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxQa9.png)

[Script deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQgyB.png)

My Execution Log shows nothing, except for the errors that I deliberately created to see if the scripts is attached to the Sales Order record.

Comment: Are you sure that the "fromId = -5" is correct in PROD? And are you sure that the "if" is working (I mean - location is 3, status is "Pending Fulfillment" and the date is today? Why don't you put a nlapiLogExecution inside just to check that you are calling nlapiSendEmail.

Comment: I played around with the nlapiLogExecution method now and it seems the email did not send because the email address could not be resolved. In the Sandbox account, the email I specified in the script was simply ignored and forwarded to the email specified in the Netsuite preferences settings. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sandbox accounts, script emails are sent to the email specified in NetSuite preferences at Setup -> Email -> Email Preferences -> SandBox and Release Preview. Email addresses specified in scripts will be ignored.